# How to read specific directory for files in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I am trying to create a simple project display page,
where you have a Project List page which displays all posts from a `Projects_List` Directory,

[heres](https://brutalism.rs/) and example of what i'm trying to recreate.

this is my folder structure:

```
project
|-- .vuepress
|-- projectslist
|   |-- post1
|   `-- post2
|-- About.md
|-- ProjectsList.md
`-- theme
    `-- layouts
        |-- ProjectsList.vue
        `-- About.vue
```

We are working in the `ProjectsList.vue`

I was looking through the site with VueDev tools and found that
vuepress sends along this data: `$site.pages`, which is an object an array of 4, which includes all of my .md files.

Now when i run this code:

```
    <ol>        
       <li v-for="page in $site.pages"> 
                {{ page.relativePath }}
       </li>
   </ol>
```

*`page.relativePath` is `<pagename>.md`*

I get this output on my page:

```
 1. About.md
 2. ProjectsList.md
 3. projectslist/post1.md
 4. projectslist/post2.md
```

So basically the `$site.pages` reads all pages from root level,
 theres also `$localePath` and `$site.base` which are both equal to `/`.

So what I am thinking is, if i can change `$site.base` to `/projectslist` it should only read the `.md` files from that folder.

heres where my vue knowledge falls short, I cant seem to change those parameters, I tried catching them in the computed & data but then i get an error that they are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

A `page` object should also contain a `path` value. You can filter `$site.pages` for paths contain `projectslist/`.

```
    <ol>        
       <li v-for="page in $site.pages">
            <span v-if="page.path.includes('projectslist/')">
                {{ page.relativePath }}
            </span>
       </li>
   </ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though @Delen Malan's post solves my issue,
I found out that using `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element
isn't a good practice

[here's a more indepth explanation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?fbclid=IwAR3dujJMJVyu5bLPiS0LneKgUEBDtzDc8K3TB5qsSp48qShvG69XDR4FmdY#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

So instead with a little tweaking with the Computed method I eventually crafted this:

```
        <li v-for="item in projectsList">
            <a href="#">
                {{ item.title }}
            </a>
        </li>

<script>
    export default {   
        computed: {
            projectsList() {                
                return this.$site.pages.filter(page => page.path.includes('projectslist/'));
            }   
        }
    }
</script>
```

We also get the following benefits:

The filtered list will only be re-evaluated if there are relevant changes to the projects array, making filtering much more efficient.
Using v-for="item in projectsList", we only iterate over active projects during render, making rendering much more efficient.

Logic is now decoupled from the presentation layer, making maintenance (change/extension of logic) much easier.